# Find position in array where element-wise multiplication with string of 1 and 0s results in max value

Tags: algorithms, optimization, arrays, big-o-notation

I have a sequence of 1s and 0s. For example: $bits = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]$. I also have an array of positive integers. For example $arr = [12, 23, 4, 6, 8, 0, 24, 72]$. I need to find the index, $i$, in $arr$ of the leftmost element of $bits$ such that

$$\sum_{j = i}^{i + \textrm{length of bits}}{bits[j - i] * arr[j]}$$

is a maximum. Essentially I am maximizing the element-wise multiplication between the two sequences starting at index $i$.

I need to solve it in $O(n\log n)$ or better, but I can only think of a way to do it in $O(n^2)$. I have a feeling prefix sums could be used but am not sure how.

Comment: You can use FFT to compute all sums in $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Could you ellaborate? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: Try working it out on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the array consist of the numbers $a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}$, and let the mask be $b_0,\ldots,b_{k-1}$. Define
$$
A = \sum_i a_i x^i, \quad
B = \sum_j b_j x^{k-1-j}.
$$
Notice that
$$
AB = \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j x^{i+k-1-j},
$$
and so the coefficient of $x^{i+k-1}$ in $AB$ is
$$
\sum_{j=i}^{i+k-1} a_j b_{j-i}.
$$
Therefore if you can calculate $AB$, you can solve your problem.

You can calculate $AB$ in $O(n\log n)$ using FFT.

Comment: So the largest coefficient will be the maximum value?

Comment: You are required to find the index $i$ at which the sum reaches its maximum. The index can be recovered from the coefficients of $AB$ in linear time.

Comment: I've tried to understand FFT but I can't. Why do we even use polynomials here? Could you show me an example of FFT with two example sequences $A$ and $B$? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: There's no need to understand FFT – all you need to know is that it is an efficient way to multiply two polynomials. As for why polynomials come in, I think the answer speaks for itself in that regard.